# axios react native implementation

Tags: react-native, axios

I got some issue on axios react native,

```
axios({
   method: 'post',
   url: url+endPoint,
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
   },
   data: data
 })
 .then((response) => {
   let cities = response.data.city || [];
   console.log('success', response.data.city);
   this.setState({
     visible: false
   })
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.log('error');
   this.setState({
     visible: false
   })
 });
```

When axios error if I set `let cities = response.data.city || [];` on success, block error wont called, axios will executed success block instead error.
Whats wrong with my code or it is bug from axios ?or I need do something ?
I hope react native master here can help me for this issue.

Comment: why u want error block to get called..and what success log statement is printing, is it some value or undefined?

Comment: what I mean when API return error if I add `let cities = response.data.city || [];`, error block not called but call success. I just want check the `response.data.city` is not null or undeifined.

if success call success block and when error call error block but when error axios not call error but success when I add that code

Comment: @alpiopio Are you sure you are getting a http error when you expect it to because you will enter the catch block only when a http error is received.

Comment: @Vandervidi yup, I m sure ...I remove that line of code `let cities = response.data.city || [];` alert error will appear.

Comment: what do you get when you console.log response?

Answer (score 0):

```
response.data.city
```

The above code is trying to read the city in response data. if there is no response data or city information then the catch block will execute.

Please check the response is correct or not or the data you are trying to read is available or not.